# Valid JSON string throws Unexpected character encountered error

Tags: c#, json, angular, websocket, asp.net-core

I'm trying to connect an angular2 client to a C# ASP.net core server. When I'm sending a JSON string using websockets from the client to the server, I get an error:

`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'Argument', line 1, position 39.`

The JSON string is as follows (The error seems to originate from the opening bracket after "Argument:"):

```
{
  "MethodName": "CreateUser",
  "Argument": { 
    "User": {
      "Attributes": [{
        "Name": "age",
        "Value": "30",
        "Type": 0
      }],
      "Email": "test@mail.com",
      "Name": "Test Name"
    },
    "Password": "1234"
  }
}
```

The code that throws the error is here:

```
public string Receive(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(input);
            InstructionServer jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstructionServer>(input); // This fails
            string methodName = jsonObject.MethodName;
            string data = jsonObject.Argument;
            return methods[methodName](1, data, "", "");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "error: " + e.Message;
        }

    }
```

I can't seem to figure out what the error is, because when I throw the JSON into an online JSON Formatter, it reports it as valid JSON. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Just to clarify on the valid JSON. I tried printing the json string out before sending it on the client and after receiving it on the server, and it is the same json string as written above.

Comment: Is that the real response or one edited by you? i.e. where there special letters inside the  json like ä. ö, ü, é  etc. ?

Comment: Have you checked your network tab and looked at the response?

Comment: @Tseng The JSON string or the error? There are no special letters and the string is exactly like that, except I added newlines in to make it more readable..

Comment: @AJT_82 I have not checked my network tab, but I did a Debug.WriteLine on the server side as well as a console.log on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Argument` appears to be expecting a `string`, but found an object. You'll have to check the format that `InstructionServer` is expecting and ensure that it will be able to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Thank you, changing the type of Argument in InstructionServer to object solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The **Receive** method expect the string value, this means you have to convert your object to JSON format to be like this:

```
"{\"MethodName\":\"CreateUser\",\"Argument\":{\"User\":{\"Attributes\":[{\"Name\":\"age\",\"Value\":\"30\",\"Type\":0}],\"Email\":\"test@mail.com\",\"Name\":\"Test Name\"},\"Password\":\"1234\"}}"
```